Why was this proof corrected? (From A Book of Abstract Algebra by Charles Pinter).
This concerns a proof that any finite subgroup $G$ of $F^\times$ for a field $F$ is cyclic under multiplication.

Theorem 1 Any finite group of nonzero elements in a field is a cyclic group. (The operation in the group is the field's multiplication.) If F* denotes the set of nonzero elements of F, suppose that G c F*, and that G, with the field's "multiply" operation, is a group of n elements. We will compare G with $Z_n$ and show that G, like $Z_n$ , has an element of order n and is therefore cyclic. For every positive integer k which divides n, the equation $x^k = 1$ has at most k solutions in F; thus, G contains k or fewer elements of order k. Charles Pinter. A Book of Abstract Algebra. page 337

Proof Image
In the new edition, instead of saying "$G$ contains $k$ or fewer elements of order $k$", it says "$G$ contains at most $k$ elements whose order is a factor of $k$." Why is the word factor included now? Why the change?
It must be that, because it's a factor of $k$, it will land on $1$. But not necessarily in $k$ steps.

Not clear what you are asking.  Both statements are true, as $x^k=1$ has at most $k$ solutions in a field.  As to what was going through the author's/editor's mind, how could we know?

Please do not use images.

Previous wording was correct , though it will not give the necessary conclusion. We might say it is inaccurate , while the argument is  incomplete , making the Proof inconclusive.
Consider "G contains k or fewer elements of order k" with $k=30$ : it talks about elements of order $30$ only , with no information about elements of order $2$ , $3$ , $15$ ...
Not all elements are accounted here.
All those might add up to some unknown value.
Current wording is correct too , though it will give the necessary conclusion.
Consider "G contains at most k elements whose order is a factor of k." with $k=30$ : it talks about elements of order $30$ , $2$ , $3$ , $15$ ...
All elements are accounted here.
All those add up to at most $30$ which is what the Author wants.
Here is one easier way ( Illustrative Example ) to see what that change makes :
Let $A=\{-100 , -99, \cdots , 0, \cdots , +99 , +100\}$ , we want to know how many elements are there.
Argument 1 : There are at most $200$ Positive numbers in that range , with a Zero , hence the count is $201$
Claim is true , Conclusion is true , though something is missing : We did not account for Negative Numbers.
Argument 2 : There are at most $200$ Positive / Negative numbers in that range , with a Zero , hence the count is $201$
Claim is true , Conclusion is true , We accounted for all numbers , it is more accurate.

No the original argument works just fine. The new version might be a bit clearer, but that's subjective.

I did say "Previous wording was correct" + "Current wording is correct too" : The Author thought that "new version might be a bit clearer" hence that minor change , @SteveD , though both are true.

The issue I have with this answer is that there is a problem with the authors original argument, but it's not in the sentence the OP highlighted. It's in the next one, counting the elements of order $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. That is where your observation should probably be applied IMO.
